# problem with selecting correct values from database

Tags: dbms

I have the following database and I'm having problems writing the correct select phrase. I am new to SQL and hope you could help me by showing me the correct way to select the desired data:

- `Employee` (`eid`, `ename`, `salary`, `did`, `classification`)
- `Department` (`did`, `dname`, `floor`, `head`)
- `dbudget` (`did`, `byear`, `budget`)
- `Project` (`pid`, `pname`, `did`, `budget`, `ddate`)
- `Onproject` (`pid`, `eid`, `fdate`)

Explanation regarding the database:

- `Department.did` = the department id of the project (what are they working on)
- `dbudget.byear`  = the year of the budget

My assignment:

1. Show the name and salary of the worker with classification 4 who earns the most.

   My query:

   ```
   select ename ,salary from Employee where classification='4'
   ```

   I don't know how to select the who earns the most....
2. Show the department id (`did`) and its name (`dname`) that have only two employees with classification 3

   My query:

   ```
   select did,dname from Department where classification='3'
   ```

   I don't know how to select so that it will show only those who have two employees with classification
3. Show department id (`did`), first year, and the year after it of departments that in two consequentive years their salary was less than 700000 (hard)

   I don't know how to create a query that will represent the first year and the year after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

```
select TOP (1) ename,salary from Employee where classification='4'
order by salary desc
```

2)

```
 select did,dname from Department
 where exists
 (select 1  from Employee 
 group by did,classification
 having count(*) = 2
 and classification = '3' and Department.did = Employee.did)
```

3)

```
 with cte as(
 select did,byear,budget,LAG(byear) OVER (partition by did order by budget) as preceeding, 
 LEAD(byear) OVER (partition by did order by budget) as next from budget
 where budget < 70000 
 )
 select distinct did,coalesce(preceeding,byear) as FirstYear,coalesce(next,byear) as NextYear from cte where cte.byear = preceeding + 1 or cte.byear = next - 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you so much for helping me! i will learn it after dinner